# C# Base64 Validation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, base64

I am receiving a base64 encoded file in my MVC controller's action from an AJAX request. Now I want to validate the base64 encodedstring. I want to allow only PDF, JPG and PNG formats.

How can I validate the base64 encoded string on the server-side, so it will not take any other type of base64 encoded files, e.g. *docx*, *exe* etc.? I want to perform server-side validation on that regardless of Javascript validation. As you may know it may be hacked.

Below is the base64 encoded version of an *exe* file. And I don't want it to be allowed.

```
string base64BinaryStr = "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";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I know, base64 string first five characters define the mime type of the file. Therefore you may be able to filter the base64 string and check which file it is, for example you can use an extension method or anything you like which resembles this:

```
public static bool IsAllowedMimeType(this string base64string) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(base64string)
    {
        return false;
    }
    string data = base64string.Substring(0,5);
    switch (data.ToUpper()) 
    {
        case "IVBOR":
            //png
            return true;
            break;
        case "/9J/4":
            //jpg
            return true;
            break;
        case "JVBER":
            //pdf
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            //other types
            return false;
    }
}
```

After implementing such an extension method you can then go with a simple `if` statement:

```
if (base64BinaryStr.IsAllowedMimeType())
{
    //what ever you want to do when type is allowed
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Karam  for answering to my question. If  malicious user change the extension in first 5 character to PNG and used base64 of an exe file. What should I do in that case? How can I validate that scenario?

Comment: I would say that you will get a corrupted file that doesn't do any harm. Mime types defines the file extension if you want to call it like that, so he will get a PNG image which is corrupted and not an executable file.

Comment: I have one more thing to ask from you. What will be the code for jpeg file extension?

Comment: @FahadFarooqi JPEG should always start with `/9j/`, you could try an online encoder where you upload any file format and it converts it to Base64 string to be more sure :)

Comment: JPEG also could be like JPG as `/9j/4`, and you can use this http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp to upload a file and check the Base64 encode.