# Decode base64 to image in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image, memorystream, linegraph

I've been searching on the internet and have not found an answer. Would you like to tell me, how to decode from `base64` to be `Image` like line graph? I've been trying to convert from `base64` to `Byte` array first and from `Byte` array to `Image`.

```
Private Function convertbytetoimage(ByVal BA As Byte())
     Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(BA)
     image = Image.FromStream(ms) 'I always get wrong in this line.
     Return image
 End Function
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the error you're getting at that line.

Comment: Base64 is a string, not a Byte().  You'll need to change the function signature and insert Convert.FromBase64String().  If it still fails then the base64 string does not represent a properly encoded image, the way it is encoded in a file on disk.  You'll need to document where it came from, or ask the programmer who wrote the code that generated the string.

Comment: the error is: Parameter is not valid @Paul Karam

Comment: @HansPassant: this isi what I code before above: 
 base64decode = rtb_code.Text
        data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64decode) –‘base64decode is the string
        rtb2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(data)
    End Sub
And then I call the code above

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your code, your problem could be using the variable name `image` instead of something like `_image`.

Keep in mind that VB is [not case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300983/is-vb-really-case-insensitive) like C# and other programming languages.

In your code, I assume you defined your `image` variable as `Image`.

To use the static `Image.FromStream(ms)`, you either need to use the fully qualified name of `Image` or change your variable name.

Here's how you can fix your code:

```
Private Function convertbytetoimage(ByVal BA As Byte())
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(BA)
    image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return image
End Function
```

Or you can do this by changing your variable name, such as:

```
Dim _image as Image

Private Function convertbytetoimage(ByVal BA As Byte())
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(BA)
    _image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return _image
End Function
```

#Update:

You can try to convert the `Byte` array to `Image` also by using [`ImageConvertor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Function convertbytetoimage(ByVal BA As Byte())
    Dim converter As ImageConverter = New ImageConverter()
    _image = CType(converter.ConvertFrom(BA), Image)
    Return _image
End Function
```

#Update 2:

Since it looks like that the main problem is with the `base64` string. Please have a look at my small demo that convert an `Image` from inside a `PictureBox` to `base64` string, then to `Byte` array, and at the end, back to an `Image`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim base64String = ConvertImageToBase64String() 'Using Functions To Make the code tidier
    Dim byteArray = ConvertBase64ToByteArray(base64String) 'Using Functions To Make the code tidier
    Dim image = convertbytetoimage(byteArray) 'Using Functions To Make the code tidier
    PictureBox2.Image = image 'since we're using a small windows form app, we'll set back the image to a second picture box.
End Sub

Public Function ConvertImageToBase64String() As String
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) 'We load the image from first PictureBox in the MemoryStream
        Dim obyte = ms.ToArray() 'We tranform it to byte array..

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(obyte) 'We then convert the byte array to base 64 string.
    End Using
End Function

Public Function ConvertBase64ToByteArray(base64 As String) As Byte()
    Return Convert.FromBase64String(base64) 'Convert the base64 back to byte array.
End Function

'Here's the part of your code (which works)
Private Function convertbytetoimage(ByVal BA As Byte())
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(BA)
    Dim image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return image
End Function
```

Note that after converting the `Image` to `base64` string, it looks something like that (keep in mind that each image is different, hence you won't get the same string):

```
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
```

If you look at the first 5 characters of the string, you notice it's equal to `/9j/4` which means that the file represented by this string is a `PNG` file, you may look at [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930474/c-sharp-base64-validation/41930683#41930683) to see how to *validate* a `base64` string.

Another note, I used a small `PNG` image, hence I used the next format:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

If you have another Format and you want to use same code, make sure to change the format.

Comment: thanks for your remind me. I've been change my code, but still not work. "Parameter is not valid" in line: _image = Image.FromStream(ms). Do u have any idea?

Comment: @Paul : Keep in mind that the OP said that the image is base64 encoded.

Comment: @VisualVincent OP also said that the base64 string is being converted to byte array then to Image. So if that doesn't work, then Either the base64 is not well converted to byte array or it's not well converted from image to base64 in first place. I tried all those snippets I posted here before I do that.

Comment: @VisualVincent: so, do u have any idea? i don't get it :)

Comment: Can you post your base64 string?

Comment: @PaulKaram this is: AAAAAAABBAoZMliFs9Xk4NC7qZ+bnaOtucjX5O/3+/v27N3MuaeWh3hrYFdQSkdDQD06ODc2Njc3ODc3NjQzMTAvLi0rKSclIyEfHhwaGBYUEhEPDg0MCwoJCAgHBwYFBAQDAwICAgICAgEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

Comment: At first sight, that doesn&#39;t look like a valid image format base64 string. Your problem could be from the way that base64 has been generated.

Comment: @WindaSariElisabethSiburian Can you post how are you converting the image to base64 then to byte array?

Comment: @Paul : True, it depends on how she converts it to a byte array. The first time I read it I got the feeling that she was converting _the string itself_ to `Byte()` and not from base64 to `Byte()`, but I'm probably wrong. :)

Comment: @PaulKaram : I didn't convert image to base64,but it's generated from a device.

Comment: @WindaSariElisabethSiburian Then most likely, it's not generated in a good way, or it's not an image at all. Anyways, I would suggest you also try to convert the base64 string to Image instead of converting it to byte array first.

Comment: @PaulKaram hm, but I'm sure that it will be an image. And if it's not generated in a good way, then error should be about base64 not in my code so it shows 'parameter is not valid'. (I hope you get what I said)

Comment: @WindaSariElisabethSiburian That's what I mean. I did create a small demo containing an image. I converted the image to base64, then to Byte array, then I converted it to image again using your code and it worked. So basically the error is within the base64 string.

Comment: o ya? i'll try like you did, Sir! thank for your all help. :)

Comment: @PaulKaram: would you like to share your codes, Sir? :)

Comment: @WindaSariElisabethSiburian Please take a look at the part `Update 2` of my answer.